# Package ifpdf Error

Tags: packages, errors

I am trying to use [amspset](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~harley/latex/). Here is my minimum code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amspset}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% info for header block in upper right hand corner
\name{}
\class{}
\assignment{}
\duedate{}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

When compiling, there is an error:

```
! Package ifpdf Error: Name clash, \ifpdf is already defined.
```

I was wondering why and how to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error occurs because the `\ifpdf` switch is getting defined by two different packages. Normally the `ifpdf` package should be used for that, but `amspset` seems to do this by its own.

To fix this, mark it as undefined after the `\documentclass` using:

```
\let\ifpdf\relax
```

I can't test it with my TeXLive installation because it doesn't have `amspset`. If it doesn't work try to move the above line around a little.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I was wondering what does let and relax mean?

Comment: @Tim: `\let` copies the meaning of one macro to another, i.e. `\ifpdf` is identical to `\relax` afterwards. The `\relax` macro is a no-op (no operation) command which, simply said, tells TeX to do nothing. By making `\ifpdf` identical to it the `ifpdf` package thinks it isn't defined yet. For a reason to long to explain here many is-the-macro-defined tests can not differ between an undefined macro and one identical to `\relax`.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, after \ifpdf being made identical to \relax by \let, \ifpdf will act as if it was undefined? \relax is a built-in command which does nothing?

Comment: @Tim: After the `\let`, `\ifpdf` will be taken as undefined but it wont cause an error if used. The `\relax` built-in command (a so called *primitive*) will be ignored by TeX when it is executed, but it is used at some points as a kind of stop marker. It is placed where you or TeX needs a command but you don't actually want to place or execute anything. See also [this TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=isdef) for further explanation about this technique.

Comment: You should also contact the author of `amspset` so the class gets fixed (it should use `ifpdf`).

Comment: @MartinSchröder: IMHO, `ifpdf` should not cause an error, but simply not try to define `\ifpdf` if it already exists. A warning would be enough in this case. I actually silently abort the loading in my `ifetex` package if `\ifetex` is already defined.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: `amspset` seems to be a rather small class, not fully up-to-date with the current state of the LaTeX art, which is also not on CTAN. I wrote an email to the author now with some improvement suggestions. I CC'ed you on it using your email address I found in one of your package manuals.

Comment: This answer fixed one conflict between packages for me in the past, but it later *caused* a conflict. (After an upgrade to texlive 2013, the package xparse became upset about the fact that `\ifpdf` was undefined.) Maybe the solution is to complain to package authors rather than to do workarounds of this type.