# Name clash, "\ifpdf is already defined" between JHEP3.cls and ifpdf.sty

Tags: errors, packages

You might be interested that there seems to be a clash between `JHEP3.cls` version 3.1.5 (from http://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/tools_JHEPlog.html) and the [`ifpdf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifpdf). I think both packages use variable `\ifpdf`, which clashes.

When I compile:

```
\documentclass{JHEP3}
\usepackage{graphics}

\author{Kuba}
\date{14/12/2012}
\abstract{ble}
\title{ble}
\keywords{ble bel}
\preprint{10932}

\begin{document} ble ble \end{document}
```

I get

```
Package ifpdf Error: Name clash, \ifpdf is already defined.
```

However, when I replace all `\ifpdf` in `JHEP3.cls` to `\ifpddf`, all `\pdftrue` to `\pddftrue`, and all `\pdffalse` to `\pddffalse`, it works fine!

I will also write to inform JHEP.

Including `\let\ifpdf\relax` (as suggested in [Package ifpdf Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11414/package-ifpdf-error)) does not help, because an error message like `Extra \fi \begin{document}` appears.

Do you have another/better idea, how to deal with this?

Comment: Could those voting to close please leave a comment stating why you think the question should be closed?

Comment: Please contact the author of `JHEP3.cls`.

Comment: Now that the question has been changed (and an actual question is asked) I think the question should stay open.

Comment: I think the question is too localized because it seems to be caused by a deficiency or incompatibility of the class to that package which could be easily fixed. Besides that, name clashes are a common problem and there are known fixes, so the question is probably a duplicate, and in this version, specific to a class, a very localized one. If it's meaningful to reopen for allowing adding more answers, just put a reopen vote. If anybody knows a canonical question with good answers about name clashes, it would be great to add a link here.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, `\ifpdf` is defined both in the class file and in the package `ifpdf` that is loaded by `graphics.cfg`. Workaround:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\documentclass{JHEP3}
```

Then `\ifpdf` will be overwritten by the class, but with a similar meaning (the class is wrong for negative numbers of `\pdfoutput`). But the warning of `ifpdf` is not triggered
and the package will not be loaded again later, because the package is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your example document compiles fine for me, probabably because it does not contain `\usepackage{ifpdf}`. Other than that, you are right, the `JHEP3` class does define `\ifpdf`. Just don't use package `ifpdf` with this class. If you have to use some package that loads `ifpdf`, then insert `\let\ifpdf\relax` before that, or even directly after the `\documentclass{JHEP3}`.