# How to tell which package is defining \ifpdf?

Tags: errors, pdftex, packages

I'm experiencing a problem similar to this one: [Package ifpdf Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11414/6853)

After upgrading to a more recent version of TeX Live, my pre-existing documents stopped compiling, with complaints that `\ifpdf` was already defined. My project is large and pulls in a lot of packages, so I don't know which one is defining `\ifpdf`. Using `\let\ifpdf\relax` after the `\documentclass`, as suggested in the answers to the other question, fixes the problem on the newer TeX Live. However, this breaks the document on older versions of TeX Live, where I still need it to compile for various reasons. (I think I'm getting malformed PDFs from pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13, but that's another topic.)

Is there any simple, straightforward way of finding out which package is defining `\ifpdf` when it shouldn't be? I could presumably figure it out by trial and error, by bisection, but this is a large, complicated project, and that would be a lot of work. If that worked, would knowing this allow me to make my file compile on both versions of TeX Live?

Is there some other way of making a more robust fix? Can I somehow test somewhere to see whether `\ifpdf` has been defined, and then define it conditionally at that point?

[EDIT] I figured out the problem. It wasn't another package, it was some code in my own .cls file, which I'd cut and pasted from somewhere probably 15 years ago:

```
\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
\else
\pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
\pdftrue
\fi

\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fi
\AtBeginDocument{
        \ifpdf
        \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
        \else
        \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.jpg,.png}
        \fi
}
```

I was able to make it run on both (modern) versions of texlive by shortening this to the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{
        \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
}
```

This probably breaks compatibility with dvi-flavored tex, but I don't care about that.

Comment: You could try using a condition: `\ifx\ifpdf\undefined\else\let\ifpdf\relax\fi`

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the suggestion, but that caused an error on the old texlive, where `\ifpdf` wasn't being defined and needed to be. I edited the question to show the solution I found that actually worked.

Answer (score 4):

`\ifpdf` is defined by package `ifpdf`. Thus you can replace your code by
`\RequirePackage{ifpdf}`.

The package/class that defines `\ifpdf` can be found by testing, whether `\ifpdf` is undefined or already defined. This can be done by

- `\show\ifpdf` stops the compilation and prints the meaning of `\ifpdf` on the console, examples for the result:

  ```
  > \ifpdf=undefined.
  l.1 \show\ifpdf
  ```

  or

  ```
  > \ifpdf=\iftrue.
  l.3 \show\ifpdf
  ```
- `\meaning\ifpdf` returns a string with the meaning of the token. This can be used to write something to the console or `.log` file, e.g.:

  ```
  \typeout{\string\ifpdf=\meaning\ifpdf}
  ```

  Example outputs:

  ```
  \ifpdf=undefined
  ```

  or

  ```
  \ifpdf=\iftrue
  ```

This methods can help narrowing down possible candidates that define `\ifpdf`. Then the package files can be inspected and searched for `\ifpdf` to find the definition.

---

BTW, the old class code definition for `\ifpdf` is wrong. Since many years `latex` also uses pdfTeX! It can generate both DVI and PDF. If a user runs `latex` he usually wants to have DVI, but `\pdfoutput` is defined and the class forces a mode switch to PDF.